# If the default nfs4 ACL 'deny access' why do default ACLs frequently contain A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy?

Tags: nfs, access-control-list

Is there an alias for deny that I could use? So far I have not had any luck removing the EVERYONE@ ACE. Maybe that a bad idea. You tell me.

I was just able to nfs4_editfacl and change the A::EVERYONE@rxtncy to D::EVERYONE@rxtncy. I'd still like to know how to do the same thing without having to use the editor.

Comment: this is mimicked on Unix permissions through NFS4 acls. What is the files mode?

Comment: If I create a new directory as root the Linux mode is rwxr-sr-x. umask is 022.

Answer (score 0):

This EVERYONE@:rxtncy was chosen by a manager or someone on the team who runs the NFS server. It is not the NFSv4 default. It's just an optional configuration someone chose. NFSv4 ACLs are default-deny so someone must have decided to override the default to make life easier for software deployment, or something.